# POSTMAN ENV FILE, different values for the same object

Tags: postman, newman, postman-testcase

currently, I am running my postman scripts using Newman by the following command Newman run [filename]  .json -e [env name]

I have the env.json file set up, but for one of my variables there could be more than 1 input and I would like to control what to call from the command line... for example in my env file now we have

```
            {
            "key": "type",
            "value": "collection",
            "description": "",
            "enabled": true
            },
```

the type could either be "collection" or "series" and I would like to be able to run the test and giving the input from the command line .. instead of creating another .json env file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set-up this specific variable with newman?

You have two different command-line-options there:

`--global-var <key=value>
--env-var <key=value>`

Just type `newman run --help` for further details.

In this case, i would suggest removing this special env-variable from your .json file and specify it over the command line option of newman.

In your case:

`newman run [filename] .json -e [env name] --env-var value="Collection"`

or

`newman run [filename] .json -e [env name] --env-var value="series"`

Hope this was helpful.

Cheers

Comment: @Milad: was my suggestion helpful?

Answer (score -1):

Below you can see the example in newman npm modules in newman/test/unit/options.test.js file and find  environment and global key words

**Example from newsman**

```
options({
   globals: './test/fixtures/run/spaces/simple-variables.json'
    }, function (err, result) {

});
```

**JSON file**

```
    {
      "name": "globals",
      "values": [{
        "key": "var-1",
        "type": "any",
        "value": "value-1"
      }, {
        "key": "var-2",
        "type": "any",
        "value": "value-2"
      }]
    }
```

Comment: Post your Code as Answer not as Image